# Check if value in dataframe exists in another column for each row

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Dataframe in question, df:

```
colA colB
1  [1, 4, 5]
4  [3, nan, nan]
```

I'm trying to return a Series which has True where colA's value is in colB's value for each row.

The result should be:

```
True
False
```

I tried: `df.colA.isin(df.colB)` - but that doesn't do the trick because colB's values are in lists

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: x['colA'] in x['colB'], axis=1)`

Comment: or `[a in b for a, b in zip(df['colA'], df['colB'])]`

Comment: Great that works, thanks! First one is good because it's memory efficient

Answer (score 1):

You need to unpack the list columns before `isin`

```
m = pd.DataFrame(df['colB'].tolist(),index=df.index).isin(df['colA']).any(axis=1)
```